# How to "await" (or .then()) a function which is asynchronous, but is wrapped in a module and doesn't return a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

(Warning: This question is absolutely *enormous* because the problem has a really complicated context. Heck, by the time I finish *writing this question* I may actually end up rubber-ducking myself into actually coming up with the solution...)

(Edit: That didn't happen. I still have no idea what to do. I hope there's not a site rule against gigantic questions like this... here goes...)

I am writing code for a Discord bot (using Node and Discord.js) which interfaces with a database. (Specifically MongoDB.) Of course, this means *double* the asynchronous behavior. When I write things in the simplest way I can, things work pretty well, and I think I generally understand Promises, callbacks, and `await` well enough that I can ensure things happen in the right sequence.

However, in refactoring my code to enhance modularity, I've come across a seemingly insurmountable annoyance: I have lost proper error catching, and things print that they have succeeded while in the same breath the module that it executed (correctly) reports that the command has failed.

First, a bit of background.

The bot has a number of commands that use the database; we'll call them "!insult" and "!joke". The idea behind these commands is that they procedurally put together an insult or a joke which is built from components that the users have added to a database. Each command has a separate "collection" (MongoDB term, think SQL table) containing their respective data that was input by users.

The bot was originally written by somebody else, and their solution for adding and removing things to/from each collection was to have four separate commands: "!insultadd", "!insultdelete", "!jokeadd" and "!jokedelete". My first thought on seeing that was "modularity, eat your heart out. Yikes." The codebase contained a lot of code reduplication like this, and so I made it my goal to abstract functionality enough that much of this reduplication could be eliminated and the codebase would be overall much easier to extend and maintain.

So, I have come up with a command called "!db". There is already a layer of modularity to be found: all that !db does, is call "sub-commands" that implement each individual function. These sub-commands are called things like "!dbadd", "!dbdelete", etc. and they are not intended to be called on their own. An important thing to note is that I wrote these sub-commands first, and only once they were all independently functional, I created !db to wrap them in a simplistic manner, just using a case statement. (For example, invoking `!db add insultsCollection "ugly"` (where `insultsCollection` is the collection of insulting adjectives) would simply end up calling `!dbadd` with the appropriate arguments.) So, originally, each sub-command would print out results on its own, using lines like `msg.channel.send('Inserted "' + selectedItem + '" into ' + selectedCollection + '.');`.

Originally, this worked just fine. !db didn't have to do anything more than simply:

```
var dbadd = require('../commandsInternal/dbadd.js');
dbadd.execute(msg,args.slice(1),db);
```

and !dbadd would take care of printing out to the user that the operation was successful, reporting what item was inserted into the DB.

However, a crucial part of this gigantic refactoring is that the external behavior and usage remain largely the same to the end user - that is, !jokeadd and its kin will remain, but their insides will be scooped out and replaced with calls to the relevant !db functions. This is where we start to run into trouble. When I would try calling something like !insultadd, this would happen:

```
> !insultadd "ugly"
Inserted "ugly" into "insultsCollection". (This is printed by !dbadd.)
The bot can now call you "ugly"! (This is printed by !insultadd.)
```

This behavior is undesired because fundamentally we want to present to the user as if it were a simple *list* of adjectives, and so we want to avoid references to e.g. the names of the collections in the DB. So, how did I correct this? The most extensible way, I think, would be to add some sort of flag to the sub-commands, like "`beQuiet`", to determine whether it prints its own stuff or not. If this were a "normal" codebase, that's probably what I'd do. But...

The commands are written in Node modules that export a couple of things: the name of the command, the cooldown of the command, etc... but most importantly, a function called `execute(msg, args, db)`. This function is how the main flow of the bot calls arbitrary commands. It looks up the name of the command, maps it to an object, and then tries to execute the `execute` method on the `command` object. Note that `execute` takes three args... a Discord.js `Message` object, the arguments for the command (an array of strings), and a MongoDB `Db` object. In order to pass a flag like "`beQuiet`" into !dbadd, I would be forced to add another arg to `execute`, which I am extremely loathe to to do because it would mean that *some* commands get "special" args for *reasons,* and... ugh. It would kinda be a breakdown of consistency, inviting things to become a total free-for-all.

So I can't pass in a flag. Ok, what next? "Well," I thought, "why don't I just move the printing into `!db`?" So I did that. My switch-case statement now looks like:

```
switch (choice) {
case "add":
    dbadd.execute(msg,args.slice(1),db);
    msg.channel.send('Inserted "' + args[2] + '" into ' + args[1] + '.');
    break;
case "delete":
    dbdelete.execute(msg,args.slice(1),db);
    msg.channel.send('"' + args[2] + '" has been removed from ' + args[1] + '.');
    break;
// ... etc
}
```

Alright, cool! So let's execute it... ok, cool, seems to work fine. Now, let's just test it with some invalid input...

```
> !db delete insultsCollection asdfasdf
Did the user give a collection that exists? : true (Debugging output)
Error: No matches in given collection. (Correct error output from !dbdelete)
"asda" has been removed from hugs. (Erroneous output from !db)
```

Uh-oh. So, why does this happen? Essentially, it's because of asynchronicity. All calls to database stuff require you to either provide a callback, or handle a Promise. (I much prefer the latter when possible.) So, !dbdelete has stuff like this:

```
var query = { value: { $eq: selectedItem} };
let numOfFind = await db.collection(selectedCollection)
                        .find(query)
                        .count();
// Note that .count() returns a Promise that resolves to an int.
// Hence the await.

if (numOfFind == 0) {
    msg.channel.send("Error: No matches in given collection.");
    return;
}
```

Convenient, right? Making the `execute()` function (which the above code is wrapped in) be an `async` function made everything a lot easier to write. I use `.then()` where appropriate, and everything's hunky-dory. But the trouble is essentially in that `return`...

(Oop, for a minute I thought I had rubber-ducked myself into solving the problem. But apparently just adding `throw` doesn't work.)

Ok, so... the problem is... whether I use `return` or `throw`, !db doesn't care. The way I think about it, making an asynchronous function call (like to db.collection().find()) sort of causes an independent "job" to start. (I am sure I'm *very* wrong about this, but this model of thinking has worked so far.) By seeing that things like:

```
db.collection(selectedCollection).deleteMany(query, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;

        console.log('Something went wrong!');
        return;
    }
    console.log('"' + selectedItem + '" has been removed from ' + selectedCollection + '.');
});
console.log("Success! Deleted the thing.");
```

would actually print "Success!" BEFORE actually deleting the item, I've come to understand that the script carries on its merry way when you call something asynchronous, and if you want it to *actually* print it *afterward,* you need to (in the case above) put it inside the callback, or use `.then()`, or `await` the result. You **have** to.

But the problem is... because of the modularity of !dbdelete, I can't do any of those. These don't work:

```
// Option 1: Callbacks.
// Doesn't work because execute() doesn't take a callback!
case "delete":
    dbdelete.execute(msg,args.slice(1),db, function(err, result) {
        msg.channel.send('"' + args[2] + '" has been removed from ' + args[1] + '.',msg);
    });
    break;

// Option 2: .then().
// Doesn't work because execute() doesn't return a Promise!
case "delete":
    dbdelete.execute(msg,args.slice(1),db)
    .then(function(err, result) {
        msg.channel.send('"' + args[2] + '" has been removed from ' + args[1] + '.',msg);
    });
    break;

// Option 3: await.
// Doesn't work because... I don't really know why but I know it doesn't work.
// Also, again, execute() doesn't return a promise so we can't await it.
case "delete":
    await dbdelete.execute(msg,args.slice(1),db);
    msg.channel.send('"' + args[2] + '" has been removed from ' + args[1] + '.',msg);
    break;
```

---

So, I'm at the end of my rope. I have no idea how to resolve this. To be honest I'm seriously considering just making .execute() return a Promise just so I can .then() it. But I really don't want to do that, especially since I don't know *how.* In short: Is there *any* way to do .then() on a function that doesn't return a promise? If I could just make it blocking, we'd be fine.

**UPDATE:** Here is the code for dbdelete.js: https://pastebin.com/LdHm3ybU
**UPDATE 2:** According to Mark Meyer, because I have used the `await` keyword, `execute()` actually *does* return a Promise! And it turns out, this solves one of the problems:

```
case "delete":
    let throwaway = await dbdelete.execute(msg,args.slice(1),db);
    message.channel.send('"' + args[2] + '" has been removed from ' + args[1] + '.');
    break;
```

This code leads to a closer-to-intended result: The print statement still always runs even on failure, but... then I just make `dbdelete.execute()` return a boolean value that I set to `false` if !db shouldn't print anything!! So, both problems are now solved! Thank you, everyone, for responding so quickly! You were really helpful! <3

Comment: You don't have any way of knowing if `dbadd.execute()` is successful?

Comment: Also, I get that you want the interface to be the same for default behavior, but can you modify the code for `dbadd.execute()`?

Comment: Fixing `.execute` to return a `Promise` would definitely be the best option, can you post its code?

Comment: At one points you say: *Making the execute() function (which the above code is wrapped in) be an async function made everything a lot easier to write.* Later you say, *Doesn't work because execute() doesn't return a Promise!*. Those two statement contradict one another — async functions return promises.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Not to my knowledge. The `async` keyword simply marks that your function is allowed to use the `await` keyword... It's just syntactic sugar, isn't it?

Comment: @Aieou -- see the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) under Return Value.

Comment: @MarkMeyer ...oh my god. Then I can just `await` it into a throwaway variable...!!! / Oh my gosh, that solves one thing! I'll edit the question to reflect this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.execute()` method is asynchronous, the ONLY way the caller can know when it's done or can know what its return value is if you design into the API and asynchronous mechanism for knowing that.  A synchronous function will return long before the asynchronous operation inside the function is done so the caller can't know when it's done or know what result it achieved.

So, you will need to create a mechanism for the caller to know when `.execute()` is done and what it's result is.  The common mechanisms are:

1. Return a promise that resolves/rejects with the final result.  The caller uses `.then()` or `await` to track it.
2. Accept a callback that will be called when the final disposition is known.
3. Use some other mechanism such as an event that is triggered on some known object (streams use this scheme).

You will need to either find some known object that the caller already knows that you can trigger an event on or you will need to change the API to have an asynchronous interface.  There is no way in Javascript to convert an asynchronous operation into a synchronous return value so you will need to change the interface.

For a one-shot returned result (not some ongoing event that triggers multiple times), the "modern" way of doing things in Javascript is to return a promise and then the caller can use `.then()` or `await` on that promise.

Comment: It turns out that because `execute()` is `async`, it actually does return a Promise! (Thanks @Mark-Meyer!) That means that I can `await` it! I just tested it out, and it behaves correctly, with some modification I elaborate on in my question edit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. I prefer "beQuiet" this way, reuse of other async logic is more or less the same way

```js
const dbAddSlient = async(..args) => {
  //your db insertion
  return result
}

const dbAdd = async(...args) => {
  //you can use try/catch to wrap your async logic
  const result = await dbAddSlient(...args) //reuse
  console.log('your log') //additional opts
  return result
}

module.exports = {
  dbAddSlient,
  dbAdd
}
```

2. When your struggle with async logic, better convert all callback to promise, then you will feel better. For example `dbAddSlient` may use `mongodriver` and async logic with callbacks, and make sure the logics all finished after `await` or `then`

```js
const dbinert = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_tests", function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
    db.collection('mongoclient_test').insert(data, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      db.close()
      resolve(result)
    })
  })
})


const dbAddSlient = async(..args) => {
  const result = await dbinert(somedata)
  //result is what you resolved, and now all the db operation is surely done
  return result
}

// some chained logic with async
(async() => {
  try {
    await someAsync1()
    const result = await dbAddSlient(data)
    await someAsync3()
  } catch (e) {
    //handle error
  }
})()

// or use promise
(() => {
  someAsync1()
    .then(() => dbAddSlient(data))
    .then((result) => someAsync3())
    .catch(e => {
      //handle error
    })
})()
```

3. The problem you are facing is you are not get used to async logic, I suggest some article to read, some practice better

https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

4. There are more complicated async logic you may face, hope this will help when you run into some logic like that

Promise.all
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Promise.race
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

generator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator

If you got any question, just comment on this answer